# How to check my geth current configuration?

Tags: go-ethereum, configuration

I have a geth node. 
I wanted to chagne **txpool.lifetime** to "24h0m0s".
So I made the configuration file using --txpool.lifetime="24h0m0s"
That file has the configuation like below.

```
[Eth.TxPool]
Locals = []
NoLocals = false
Journal = "transactions.rlp"
Rejournal = 3600000000000
PriceLimit = 1
PriceBump = 10
AccountSlots = 16
GlobalSlots = 4096
AccountQueue = 64
GlobalQueue = 1024
Lifetime = **86400000000000**
```

I had launched my geth using that configuration file.

Now I want to check current configuration of running geth.

Is there a way to check the configuration of running geth?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the starting command and add `dumpconfig` after `geth` such as:

```bash
$ geth dumpconfig --txpool.lifetime="24h0m0s" [... your other options]
```

For context re your time config,

- 24 hours =
- 24 * 3600 seconds =
- 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 nanoseconds =
- **86,400,000,000,000** nanoseconds

Which is what you have in your file, so you're good to go.